# Pausing a Storyboard in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, storyboard

I'm gonna pause a Storyboard in WPF, so I've used below code :

```
Storyboard TheStoryboard;

//Constructor 
public window
{
    TheStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("TheStoryboardName");
}

private void MenuItemPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TheStoryboard.Pause();
}
```

But nothing happen!
What is the right way to do that ?

Comment: Did the event actually fire? Did you wire up the 'MenuItemPause_Click' correctly in the XAML? Did you turn it off and on again? ;)

Comment: I'm dead sure the event fires. yes, I did. what do you mean by `turn it off and on again`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem.
I've been added a trigger for beginning the storyboard as follows :

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TheStoryboardName}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

I've omitted it, and added a C# code for beginning the storyboard :

```
Storyboard TheStoryboard;

//Constructor 
public window
{
    TheStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("TheStoryboardName");
    TheStoryboardName.Begin();
}
```

Now , the following code works well.

```
private void MenuItemPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TheStoryboard.Pause();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

But it's wired that the behavior in .NET Framework 3.5 & 4 seems to be different.

I had a project which was built via .NET Framework 3.5 and then changed to .NET Framework 4.

In 3.5, I also had the trigger you mentioned to begin the storyboard. But I still could pause it in my code.

In 4, I couldn't pause the storyboard with the trigger.

So I moved it and now the storyboard work as I expect.

Thank you for your sharing.